# qt online installer can't extract metadata on windows

Tags: windows-10, installation, extract, repository

Every time I try to install qt 5.12 using the qt online 3.1.1 installer for windows, I get an error during the extraction process saying that it is unable to open the archive. I tried to disable repositories that had problem, but I realized soon enough that every repository had problems.

I have tried almost everything I know (I still don't know much about how Windows works), but I usually fix my problems.

Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image: https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ4ukA7ZPEy2wfGjlR4ytlBF9yw70H9FCkRy]

Comment: It seems the trusted installer has no permissions to this private folder

Comment: I also tried with admin permissions, but I still get the same error. Shouldn't my "Temp" folder be public by default? I never got that error with previous versions of this installer or any installer at all for that matter.

Comment: No.  I see it only needs User privileges.  so far 10% done  no problem on WIn8 here  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0qcf.png

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install too, but failed.  It was trying to open an EXE that it already started just prior. So ProcMon verified it as a Sharing Violation.

Call or write to Qt for support.

[image]